# Domain-Permissions with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, tomcat, permissions

Imagine a website permissions similar to Reddit.  A specific user-account has access to "SUPER-MOD" for "/r/subreddit-A" and "MOD" on "/r/Subreddit-B" and finally "BANNED" on "/r/Subreddit-C"

The way our spring security config is currently setup is we have the concept(s) of SUPER-MOD, MOD, USER, etc... but not SUPER-MOD(domain-A).

Clearly, writing my own code for this is not rocket science, but I was wondering if there was a common or standard interface for these types of permissions.

P.S.  We're using Spring MVC / Tomcat.  Articles & tutorials welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I have usually dealt with roles is typically using the [Expression-Based Access Control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) with Spring. Since you seem to have most of the roles and permissions defined it should be a piece of cake getting them out of the security context.

Just make sure you have `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` because lack of that will obviously make the annotations useless.

Anyway hope that helps.